# The combination PostScript and UTF-8 is not supported

Tags: ms-word, postscript

I am new to linux and antiword.
I want to convert word to PostScript.

I am able to create the file but the PS file is not openning.

And at the time of conversion it is giving error like

"The combination PostScript and UTF-8 is not supported"

Answer (score 2):

This utility 'antiword', the latest version of which I found to be 0.37 (21 Oct. 2005) ships with a few *Readme* files.

It explains itself in its own *History* file as such:

> The name comes from: "The antidote against people who send Microsoft(R) Word files to everybody, because they believe that everybody runs Windows(R) and therefore runs Word".

The same file says about its current version:

> Beta release, for evaluation by the public.

And it also says, under the header *Known Limitations*:

> [....]
>   2) Antiword doesn't show all the images included in a Word document.
>   [....]
>   7) PostScript ouput will not work in combination with UTF-8. It only works in combination with character sets ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2 and ISO-8859-5.
>   8) Antiword's error messages are not very helpful.

So here you are. The behavior you are experiencing is exactly as is documented.  :-)

@Tushar: It's also recommended to read the included *FAQ* document.